# Empty description in Web Entities of Google Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-vision

If you try Google Vision API with follwoing demo-image.jpg
[image] shown in [QuickStart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart), you will get a record with empty description and score of 0.7024 in “[Web Entities](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#WebEntity)”. Why!?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is **working as intended**. If you check the getDescrition() method from Java API libraries, you see that getDescrition() could [return value or null for none](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/WebEntity.html#getDescription()).

Comment: But what it means to have a null description while having a score!?

Comment: I think that means we know for a degree of certainty that this is from web page X or Y, but that does not mean that we have [description *in English*](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#WebEntity) of the entry.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!